# Why do we synchronize lazy singletons but not eager ones?

Tags: oop, synchronization, singleton, lazy-initialization

Typical lazy singleton:

```
public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton INSTANCE;

    private Singleton() {

    }

    public static synchronized Singleton getInstace() {
        if(INSTANCE == null)
            INSTANCE = new Singleton();

        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Typical eager singleton:

```
public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Why are we not concerned about synchronization with eager singletons, but have to worry about synchronization with their lazy cousins?

Comment: Because there is no possible race condition?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - But lazy singletons don't race, they just amble along.

Comment: Thanks @OliCharlesworth (+1) - can you explain with a more in-depth answer?

Comment: @HotLicks the instantiation and the check create an inherent race

Comment: @icepack - I guess you didn't see the implied `;)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since  an eager singleton is initialized when the class if first loaded into memory (jit) and this happens only once. However if two clients will try to call the singleton instance method from two threads at the same time, two singletons may be created.

Comment: How do two singletons get created??

Comment: If not synchronized, both threads may reach the is null check, see that it is true and create a new instance

Comment: How can a static have more than one value?

Comment: It wont have 2 values. but it may still call new() twice and might even return 2 different objects to the 2 clients. there is a lot of information on that issue. if you want i will give you more info and links

Comment: both threads reach the null check and see it is true. thread A creates a new object assigns it to INSTANCE and returns it to client A. just now thread B which thought that INSTANCE is null creates a new object assigns it to INSTANCE and retruns it to client B. INSTANCE always holds a single value, however both clients get different objects. and this is just one example of what might go wrong here

Comment: And by the way, using the synchronized is not good enough. you also need to declare INSTNACE as volatile to make sure that the code works. and also it is very inefficient since it will lock the singleton every time getInstance() is called, although it should only be locked on init. so in short - avoid lazy init when possible

Comment: Yes, but while that may be two objects it's not two singletons.  By definition there's only one singleton.

Comment: You should read about why the double check locking idiom  is broken

Comment: And just to wrap things up, while there is only one singleton at any single time in your example, there is more than one singleton instance throughout the porgram life cycle, and this is not controlled by the client. I am aware that there are lazy init patterns that do work and are effective, but: a. They don't use the code the OP posted, and you did not suggest thir code either. b. In the vast majority of cases they offer no real benefit over eager init, since the first time the class is loaded is just before calling getInstance() anyway.

Comment: worth noting that double lock problematics are mostly inherent to the Java language, not to the concept itself

Comment: @DirtyMikeAndTheBoysless, glad my answer helped. would appreciate an upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

Eager instantiation does not require **explicit** synchronisation for sharing the reference of the field because the JVM will have handled it for us already as part of the class loading mechanism.

To elaborate in more detail, before a class becomes available to any thread for use, it will have been loaded, verified and initialised. The compiler rewrites the static field assignment into this initialisation stage and via the rules of the Java Memory Model and the underlying hardware architecture will ensure that all threads who access that class will see this version of the class. This means that the JVM will have handled any hardware barriers etc for us.

That said, I would recommend marking the eager initialisation final. This will make your intent clearer and the compiler will enforce that the eager initialisation never changes. If it did, then concurrency control would be required again.

```
private static **final** Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
```

FYI If you are interested, section 5.5 of the [Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.5) covers this in much more detail. A couple of choice snippets from the spec are

```
*"Because the Java Virtual Machine is multithreaded, 
initialization of a class or interface requires careful 
synchronization"*

*"For each class or interface C, there is a unique initialization lock LC"*

*9&10) "Next, execute the class or interface initialization method of C"
"If the execution of the class or interface initialization 
method completes normally, then acquire LC, label the Class object for 
C as fully initialized, notify all waiting threads, release LC, and 
complete this procedure normally."*
```

It is in step 10 of the spec where the static fields will have been set, and the use of a lock (LC) is used to ensure that only one thread performs the initialisation and that the result is shared correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Because in the latter example the instance of the Singleton is always present when the `getInstance` is called - nothing to synchronize here. That is in contrary to the first example where the instance isn't necessary initialized yet. In this case the `getInstance` contains critical section (the `if` and it's body) which needs to be protected (e.g. by synchronization) against simultaneous access.

Comment: Although this raises an interesting point (at least, in my head!); what happens if the static initializer in another class decides to call `Singleton.getInstance()`?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth that's why the `synchronized` keyword is present in the `getInstance` signature

Comment: I mean in the eager version.  (My question is really nothing to do with concurrency; I just realised I didn't know how Java defined the relative order of static initializations of different classes.)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Ah, misunderstood you. I believe that's implicitly answered in the omerschleifer answer - JIT probably takes care of consistency here (though my knowledge of Java is limited, maybe someone more knowledgeable can answer)

Comment: Static initialization of a class is inherently synchronized by the JVM.  Anything in the static init method of the class will be executed only once, and before the class is made "visible".